# Aligning Tables and TiKz Pictures Vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have the following codes.
I want to pull the tables to the top of the page
so that tables and the tikz picture are aligned
vertically at top of the page (as shown in the figure).
I need your help in this direction.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw[fill=white] (-45,-5) rectangle (45,65);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `tikzpicture` is considered as a simple `char` and it's aligned according it's `baseline` which by default is its `south` anchor ([see page 124 in pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=124). Therefore, in your code the central point of both tabulars are aligned with tikzpicture's southern point.

You can change this alignment with tikzpicture's option `baseline`. You can decide where to  align the picture with `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` or `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` or similar expressions.

About `tabular` you can also use the optional parameter to align them along it's top, center or bottom: `\begin{tabular}[t]{...}`.

One example aligning to center:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), scale=0.4]
\draw[fill=white] (-45,-5) rectangle (45,65);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `[t]` for the tabulars and `[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.4]` for the tikzpicture worked exactly as I wanted.

Comment: How can I add a new table below of the figure (by preserving the previous two)?

Comment: @bkarpuz You can declare `tabular` inside `tabular`, so declare new `tabular` that contains pervious elements and the new tabular can be declared as the central element on the second row.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to achieve this is to make the tables part of the `tikzpicture`, i.e. to put them in nodes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw[fill=white] (-45,-5) rectangle (45,65);
\node[anchor=north east] at (-45,65){\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}};
\node[anchor=north west] at (45,65) {\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I arrange it by brute force using `minipages`. It's a easy way to work with `floats`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent \begin{minipage}{1.1cm}\vspace*{-7cm}{
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{35.9cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
  \draw[fill=white] (-45,-5) rectangle (45,65);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{1.2cm}\vspace*{-7cm}{
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\ \hline
  1 & A \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You do not use any float and minipage has, in fact, nothing to do with floats…

Comment: Well, the idea was to refer the minipage as 'floating' element. Sorry, if i didn't use the figure or table enviroment who does create a floating element.

Comment: I just mentioned it because in terms of TeX floating is a very different concept than, say, in web design…